# How to format a Cursor value in a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter for an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, cursor, expandablelistview, simplecursoradapter

Wow... that is a pretty long title. But here's the gist of my question.

I return a cursor that contains data from an SQLiteDatabase table called Budget. One of the columns in the database stores the currency amount for an item.

The table looks something like this.

```
_id   Item   Amount
1     Book   299.99
```

Right, so I return the cursor, make use of my own custom adapter which inherits from SimpleCursorTreeAdapter and then load the data into an ExpandableListView.

Now the question is, how do I go about formatting how the Amount is displayed. I know how to do the actual formatting (NumberFormat to local currency), but I want to know how to gain access to the cursor's value to modify it, before it pushes into the ExpandableListView.

Do I access the cursor or should I be dabbling in the SimpleCursorTreeAdapter methods?

I would appreciate any advice and direction as I'm completely stumped on this one.

Comment: Also, I should add that a ViewBinder would do the trick, but I'm working with API level 4 and ViewBinder has only been around since api level 5.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 0):

Right, so after much digging, with trial and error the solution is pretty simple.

If you are using `API5` and up, you can just use a ViewBinder to customise your output. 
If you are using `API4` and up, you can't use a ViewBinder, so you'll have to override the bindChildView method of your custom adapter.

Hope that helps someone.